# Datagridview Generates empty rows when combobox value change

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagridview that contains a combobox column and a dateTimePicker, 
the problem is after choosing the combobox value the gridview automcatically add 3  or more **empty rows**, I don't know where the problem is

So Here is what happens:
when I choose from the drop down list and move to next cell empty rows appear or even when i write in a textbox and move to click on other cell emtpy rows appear

[image]

[image: Empty Rows appears Automatically]

here is the code of how i generate the datagridview:

```
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvcombo =new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                dgvcombo.ValueType = typeof(string);
                dgvcombo.Name = cntrlname;
                dgvcombo.HeaderText = Headertext;
                dgvcombo.DataPropertyName = cntrlname;
                dgvcombo.Tag = ToolTipText;
                dgvcombo.DataSource = Data.GetLookup(ComboData[0]);
                dgvcombo.ValueMember = ComboData[1];
                dgvcombo.DisplayMember = ComboData[2];
                GridViewList.Columns.Insert(ColumnIndex, dgvcombo);
private void GridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == DateColumnIndex && e.RowIndex != -1)
            {ateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
                    dateTimePicker.TextChanged += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker_OnTextChange);
                    GridView.Controls.Add(dateTimePicker);
                    dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                    Rectangle dgvRectangle = GridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
                    dateTimePicker.Size = new Size(dgvRectangle.Width, dgvRectangle.Height);
                    dateTimePicker.Location = new Point(dgvRectangle.X, dgvRectangle.Y);
                    dateTimePicker.CloseUp += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker_CloseUp);


private void dateTimePicker_OnTextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView.CurrentCell.Value = dateTimePicker.Text.ToString();
            //dateTimePicker.Visible = false;
        }
```

datagridview is bind to a sql datatable and so is combobox.

Comment: @SMohamed..when is a new row get added to the datagridview? Also check any code is there in combox selected index change method..

Comment: there is no select index change in combobox, and the new rows is added when I move from one cell to another

Comment: not allow the user to add rows into the DataGridView, i.e. set the AllowUserToAddRows property of the DataGridView to false. Add a Button on the form to let the user add a new DataRow in the DataTable instead.

Comment: When I remove the gridview_cellclick that shows datetimepicker, the problem doesn't occur, I don't know why

Comment: does ur code contain full lines of GridView_CellClick

Comment: just the one that I wrote in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78015/discussion-between-sachu-and-smohamed).